# AsciiDoc Include only values from custom annotation

Tags: asciidoc

I would like to document my project utilizing AsciiDoc.

I have a class like the one below that has comments that outline some details about the steps being processed in a method. I would like to make these comments the contents of certain sections of my .adoc.

```
public RequestResponse processRequest(UserRequest request){
   /* First retrieve info from db calling the stored procedure
      dbo.StoredProcedure with input parameters A,B,C */
   DbResponse dbResponse = dao.getResponse(request);

   // Call method to calculate all scenarios for the Example request
   CalcResult calcResult = util.calculateStuff(request.getAmountList());

   /* Format the response to include the fields from the calcResult as well
      as the request details returned from the DB result set */
   return util.formatResponse(dbResponse,calcResult );
}
```

Ultimately this documentation would then be used to provide other developers an outline of how certain REST calls process without them having to go into the source code and look at all the steps.

I am new to AsciiDoc and may be way off base with this use case.

Comment: What exactly is your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though initially you did not ask a formal question, I believe that the apparent goal of documenting a (REST) API utilizing AsciiDoc is noble, so for your potential questions, I'll try to point you in promising directions:

**Q**: What would be a suitable format for documentation comments in general?

**A**: Javadoc. Your programming language looks like C++ or Java. A popular standard for the format of automatically extractable comments is the JavaDoc format. Prefix comments starting with two asterisks and line-end comments starting with three instead of just two slashes are meant for the documentation generator: `/** Prefixed API doc */ int foo; /// postfixed API doc`
Using Javadoc provides the advantage that there are many existing tools that understand this convention, in particular development environments (IDEs).

**Q**: Are there existing processors that extract such documentation comments?

**A**: Javadoc itself (Java only, I assume), Doxygen (C-Like languages), Asciidoclet[1][2]. Asciidoclet is a Doclet[3], which is sort of a plugin for the regular Javadoc, which is usually somehow integrated into your IDE. Asciidoclet understands asciidoc, or rather asciidoctor syntax, inside of the doc comments. You may be able to repurpose some of these processors' components for your needs.

**Q**: What is considered best practice when documenting REST APIs?

**A**: You'll quickly see that Swagger (http://swagger.io/) is popular for REST API documentation. But it does not use asciidoc.

**Q**: How can I use asciidoc markup to document my API?

**A**: Search the net for "using asciidoc to document APIs". Look at the top links. You'll find that some people have had some success in reconciling Javadoc with Swagger and Asciidoc. However, it seems to me that they were not aware of Asciidoclet.

- [1] https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoclet
- [2] http://asciidoctor.org/news/2013/06/03/asciidoclet-announcement/
- [3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doclet

Comment: Since this answer was created there is a tool

https://github.com/verhas/jamal/

That you can list as a tool to answer

"Are there existing processors that extract such documentation comments?"

Jamal is fairly general purpose and can be used for practically for any progrmming language compared to the tools listed.